# how to make responsive DataTable in mobile version and Tablet version

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, datatable

I am working on responsive design of page. which contains bootstrap DataTable. I am not able to scroll DataTable in mobile version browser and Tablet version browser to see other Table header name and it's data. so how can I fix this issue that enable to scroll me to see data in DataTable with searchBar and Pagination?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true
  });

  new $.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader(table);
});
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.3.2/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" />

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
      <th>Extn.</th>
      <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011-04-25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
      <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011-07-25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
      <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009-01-12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
      <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012-03-29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
      <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008-11-28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
      <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012-12-02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
      <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod</td>
      <td>Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012-08-06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
      <td>9608</td>
      <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona</td>
      <td>Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010-10-14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
      <td>6200</td>
      <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen</td>
      <td>Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009-09-15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
      <td>2360</td>
      <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya</td>
      <td>Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008-12-13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
      <td>1667</td>
      <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena</td>
      <td>Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008-12-19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
      <td>3814</td>
      <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.3.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you convert your code into a minimal reproducible snippet?

Comment: I have tested locally, with your HTML/CSS/Javascript and running it with a mobile emulator (inside browser Dev Tools) and the problem did not reproduce.